# Передача значений переменной в другую функцию С++

Tags: c++

И снова здравия вам люди добрые. Суть проблемы такова. Есть у меня переменная, значение которой после прохождения через void menu() меняется. Далее нужно каким-то образом перенести это значение в int main(). Пробовал исользовать глобальную переменную, но натыкался на то, что значение ее меняется только внутри первой функции, а во вторую переходит глобальное значение, которое было задано с самого начала.

```
using namespace sf;

int dif=0, easy=1, hard=2;

void menu(RenderWindow & app)
{
...

    bool isMenu = 1;
    int menuNum = 0;

    while (isMenu)
    {
    ...
        if (Mouse::isButtonPressed(Mouse::Left))/
        {
            if (menuNum == 1)
            {
                ::dif=::easy;
                isMenu = false;
            }
            if (menuNum == 2) 
            {
                ::dif=::hard;
                isMenu = false;
            }
            if (menuNum == 3) { app.close(); isMenu = false; }
        }
    ...
    }
}


int main()
{   
    std::ofstream out;         
    out.open("param.txt");

    if (out.is_open())
    {   
        if(dif==easy) out << "256 " << "4" << std::endl;
        if(dif==hard) out << "512 " << "8" << std::endl;     
        else out << "not found" << std::endl;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ничего не понимаю. Приведите [минимальный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), который бы демонстрировал вашу проблему. И еще - вы знаете что-то о локальных переменных? о том, что функции могут возвращать значения?...

Comment: постарался сократить писанину до необходимого. да, про локальные переменные я знаю, потому и пытался область видимости расширить ::
возврат переменной из первой функции почему-то вызывал преждевременное закрытие программы, хотя, это уже в виду моей криворукости, полагаю

Comment: `...` не будет компилироваться :( Вы можете понять, что от вас нужен минимальный **компилируемый** код с вашей проблемой?

Comment: Во-первых, использование глобальных переменных для передачи значения - неоспоримое зло наряду с использование goto для построения циклов. Во-вторых, почему вы не хотите использовать возвращаемое значение функции для передачи возвращаемого значения (оцени тофталогию?). В-третьих, глобальные переменные на то и глобальные, что видны отовсюду. Ну и в-четвертых, в вашем "минимальном примере" нету даже примера использования вашей функции (пример без примера)

Comment: Проблема такая, что компилируемый вариант я скидывал в самый первый раз, но т-щ Harry подметил, что из-за громоздкости ничего не понятно. Скидывать ли его повторно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пришлось заново перечитывать матчасть по указателям, но оно того стоило. Костыльно, но работает. Объявил глобально переменную TheOne и указатель на нее TheTwo, с которым далее и работал.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace sf;

    int TheOne=0;
    int *TheTwo=&TheOne;

void menu(RenderWindow & app)
{

    Texture menuTextureEasy, menuTextureHard, menuTextureExit, menuBackground;

    menuTextureEasy.loadFromFile("images/easy.png");
    menuTextureHard.loadFromFile("images/hard.png");
    menuTextureExit.loadFromFile("images/exit.png");
    menuBackground.loadFromFile("images/background.png");

    Sprite menu1(menuTextureEasy), menu2(menuTextureHard), menu3(menuTextureExit), menuBg(menuBackground);

    bool isMenu = 1;
    int menuNum = 0;

    menu1.setPosition(180, 180);
    menu2.setPosition(180, 250);
    menu3.setPosition(180, 320);

    while (isMenu)
    {
        menu1.setColor(Color::White);
        menu2.setColor(Color::White);
        menu3.setColor(Color::White);
        menuNum = 0;
        app.clear(Color(129, 181, 221));


        if (IntRect(180, 180, 300, 50).contains(Mouse::getPosition(app))) { menu1.setColor(Color::Green); menuNum = 1; }
        if (IntRect(180, 250, 300, 50).contains(Mouse::getPosition(app))) { menu2.setColor(Color::Blue); menuNum = 2; }
        if (IntRect(180, 320, 300, 50).contains(Mouse::getPosition(app))) { menu3.setColor(Color::Red); menuNum = 3; }

        if (Mouse::isButtonPressed(Mouse::Left))
        {
            if (menuNum == 1)
            {
                ( *TheTwo)+=1;
                //system("start Sb4_Puzzle.exe");
                isMenu = false;
            }
            if (menuNum == 2) 
            {
                ( *TheTwo)+=2;
                //system("start Sb4_Puzzle.exe");
                isMenu = false;
            }
            if (menuNum == 3) { app.close(); isMenu = false; }
        }

        app.draw(menuBg);
        app.draw(menu1);
        app.draw(menu2);
        app.draw(menu3);
        app.display();
    }
}


int main()
{   
    ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE);

    RenderWindow app(VideoMode(512,512), "Main menu");
    menu(app);
    app.setFramerateLimit(60);

    std::ofstream out;         
    out.open("param.txt"); 
    if (out.is_open())
    {   
        if(*TheTwo==1) out << "256 " << "4" << std::endl;
        if(*TheTwo==2) out << "512 " << "8" << std::endl;    
    }

}
```

Сама программа представляет из себя менюшку к игре, где можно выбрать уровень сложности или вовсе выйти из игры. Комментарии постирал, поскольку здесь они в абракадабру превращаются.